# How can I solve this equation analytically. $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{2x+\sqrt{3x...}}}-100x\sin(x)=0$

Tags: calculus

How can I solve this equation analytically. $$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{2x+\sqrt{3x...}}}-100x\sin(x)=0$$

Comment: Isn't zero a solution?

Comment: I want the roots of equation.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe a nonzero root can be obtained analytically? What is the source of this question?

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something here, but for what values of $x$ is that root expression well-defined, i.e. converges?

Comment: @SimonS - for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for there to be an analytical expression. However, note that the root term increases like $\sqrt{x}$, so that as $x$ becomes large, the roots become closer and closer to $n\pi$.

Attached is a plot of the distance between the first hundred roots and $n\pi$. As you may see, the graph decreases logarithmically:

[image]

Comment: Sorry,I edited the question

Comment: @Ehegh - that extra 100 only makes my answer "more correct".